# How can I access to my webservice outside my lan

Tags: node.js, windows, mknetworkengine

I've created a webservice with nodeJs and Express.
In the lan I can access with 192.168.0.xxx:8080, but now I wanna access since other place outside the lan, I need help I don't know how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the firewall blocks it? Anyway, it would be better to use some deployment service, like Heroku to publish it.

Comment: By the way, outside your LAN, you won't use your NAT address. Use whatismyip.com or any similar service to check your public IP.